# Android elements in action bar not shown

Tags: android

Im going through Android tutorials right now. I have a question though. Im at the Action Bar part. It says some things can be added to the Action Bar but not shown. But it never explains why you would do this. If you cant see them on the action bar then surely you cant use them so what is the point? It also says Settings should be in the overflow but never explains why. Is that just a best practices thing? Also it doesnt explain what the overflow is but im guessing thats just for things that dont fit on the screen and can be accessed through a button click?

Answer (score 1):

You can add all the items on the action bar for all you want, but there is a limited screen size that developers need to deal with. Hence, the most useful options are always shown and the one's not required that much are put in the actionbar overflow menu. As far as the settings in the overflow menu, its really a choice. Its not enforced upon. The overflow menu is basically a tool for providing the end user with a quick access to the most common screens rather than navigating through the app. Hope that helps